# Consolidating shard data into single persistent DB in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have software that generates a large amount of data in a short period of time, and is stored in a single MongoDB database. To increase write performance we are looking into setting up a sharded cluster to handle the incoming data. Because this is all being done on amazon ec2 instances, we would prefer to consolidate our data from the sharded cluster to a single persistent server once the process is done to save on cost. Obviously we can write a python script that will port the data off the cluster when done, but I am hoping there is a cleaner, more automated method. Once the data has been written, the access is all read-only and a single server can handle the workload sufficiently. I was looking for some solution combining replica sets and sharding, but that doesn't seem to to be the way those work. Any suggestions for how to best implement this architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to migrate a MongoDB with zero downtime is to create a replica-set consisting of the old and the new servers and removing the old ones as soon as the new have synced. But that doesn't work when the old database is sharded and the new one isn't, because shards are build from replica-sets, not the other way around. That means that you have to copy the database the old-fashioned way. There are two methods to do this:

1. The network method: Use the command [`db.copyDatabase(<remote_db_name>, <local_db_name>, <remote_host>, <remote_username>, <remote_password>)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/copydb/#dbcmd.copydb)
    on the destination to copy the database from the source via network.
2. The file method: Do a [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) on the source to export the data to a file. Then do a [`mongorestore`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) on the new server to import it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Is it possible to do this more efficiently using replica sets.  That is, can the mongos and a persistent mongod be members of a replica set?  Does that make any sense?

Comment: @TomSwifty Your problem is that your source is sharded and your destination is not. Each shard of a cluster is an independent replica-set. That means to migrate a sharded cluster, you need to clone each of its shards separately. So your destination must have the same sharding-configuration.

Comment: @TomSwifty But what you could do is set up a destination cluster identical to the source and after the migration you [remove the sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-shards-from-cluster/).